# Is this algorithm secure?

Tags: algorithm-design, hmac, bcrypt

I recently found [this site](http://www.phpgangsta.de/schoener-hashen-mit-bcrypt), proposing a hashing algorithm for passwords.

They describe the following:

1. pad the password on both sides with `SHA1(email)` to `4 * length(password)`
2. `HMAC(padded password, global salt)`
3. choose a random salt of 22 characters
4. `bcrypt(hmac, salt)`

Is this algorithm secure? I think it might be a security flaw to pad the password on both sides with the same text, and I see no point in using a global salt *and* a salt which is chosen randomly for every password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Points 3 and 4 are a secure way of storing the input to bcrypt (with appropriate choice of parameters for bcrypt).

Points 1 and 2 aren't necessary but don't harm:

- they would add a small amount of extra computation for an attacker is possession of the password database that wants to do a dictionary attack;
- the attacker wouldn't be able to straight-out use a standard cracking tool as it is a custom scheme, they would need to modify existing tools or develop their own.

Comment: so it doesn't matter that the `sha1(email)` is used on both sides of the password?

Comment: That's right; provided the password is there in full in the input to HMAC (if HMAC is being used with a standard hash algorithm), adding additional entropy-less data doesn't lower the entropy of the output.